# MongoDB - merge collection and map - can performance be improved

Tags: java, oracle, mongodb, plsql, merge

The function below merge word MongoDB collection and map content like this:

Collection:
cat  3,
dog  5

Map:
dog  2,
zebra 1

Collection after merge:
cat 3,
dog 7,
zebra 1

We have empty collection and map with about 14000 elements.

Oracle PL/SQL procedure using one merge SQL running on 15k RPM HD do it in less then a second.

MongoBD on SSD disk needs about 53 seconds.

It looks like Oracle prepares in memory image of file operation 
and saves result in one i/o operation.

MongoDB probably does 14000 i/o - it is about 4 ms for each insert. It is corresponds with performance of SSD.

If I do just 14000 inserts without search for documents existence as in case of merge everything works also fast - less then a second.

My questions:

1. Can the code be improved?
2. Maybe it necessary to do something with MongoDB configuration?

Function code:

```
public void addBookInfo(String bookTitle, HashMap<String, Integer> bookInfo)
{
    // insert information to the book collection
    Document d = new Document();
    d.append("book_title", bookTitle);
    book.insertOne(d);
    // insert information to the word collection
    // prepare collection of word info and book_word info documents
    List<Document> wordInfoToInsert = new ArrayList<Document>();
    List<Document> book_wordInfoToInsert = new ArrayList<Document>();
    for (String key : bookInfo.keySet())
    {
        Document d1 = new Document();
        Document d2 = new Document();
        d1.append("word", key);
        d1.append("count", bookInfo.get(key));
        wordInfoToInsert.add(d1);
        d2.append("book_title", bookTitle);
        d2.append("word", key);
        d2.append("count", bookInfo.get(key));
        book_wordInfoToInsert.add(d2);
    }
    // this is collection of insert/update DB operations
    List<WriteModel<Document>> updates = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();
    // iterator for collection of words
    ListIterator<Document> listIterator = wordInfoToInsert.listIterator();
    // generate list of insert/update operations
    while (listIterator.hasNext()) 
    {
        d = listIterator.next();
        String wordToUpdate = d.getString("word");
        int countToAdd = d.getInteger("count").intValue();
        updates.add(
            new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
                new Document("word", wordToUpdate),

                new Document("$inc",new Document("count", countToAdd)),
                new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)
            )
        );
    }
    // perform bulk operation
    // this is slowly
    BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult = word.bulkWrite(updates);
    boolean acknowledge = bulkWriteResult.wasAcknowledged();
    if (acknowledge)
        System.out.println("Write acknowledged.");
    else
        System.out.println("Write was not acknowledged.");
    boolean countInfo = bulkWriteResult.isModifiedCountAvailable();
    if (countInfo)
        System.out.println("Change counters avaiable.");
    else
        System.out.println("Change counters not avaiable.");
    int inserted = bulkWriteResult.getInsertedCount();
    int modified = bulkWriteResult.getModifiedCount();
    System.out.println("inserted: " + inserted);
    System.out.println("modified: " + modified);
    // insert information to the book_word collection
    // this is very fast
    book_word.insertMany(book_wordInfoToInsert);
}
```

Comment: There is something I don't get: You do upsert operations on an "empty collection"? Furthermore, please provide sample documents – I really don't want to reconstruct how they could look like from the code.

Comment: Thank you for replay. Collection of course can be empty and can be not. But there are not much difference in execution time (53 sec) in this 2 cases: 1) empty collection, 14 000 words in map, after it - repeat operation  - collection with 14 000 words and 14 000 words in map - the result is just doubling counters for words in collection. Content of the collection look like this: >db.word.find() {"_id" : ObjectId("56cf.."), "word"  : "frowing", "count" : 56}        My question is it possible to use other Mongo API functions or change some how MongoDB configuration to speed up the operation.